# EF Code First: link dbset to existing SQL view in separate database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4.1

Let's say I create a new Entity Framework Code First entity like this (keeping simple for question):

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int? ProductManager { get; set; }
}
```

`ProjectManager` represents an optional employee ID

Is there a way to pull the employee's name (and possibly other supplemental, non-modifiable info) from a separate database table or view (You can infer a simple table of `employeeID`, `employeeName` elsewhere)?

How can I approach this?  Do I have to use Database first?

The goal being to simply show this information in index or details view in MVC if there is a match - not to edit the employee information.

Comment: I don't see anything called ProjectManager.  Did you mean ProductManager?  Or is ProductManager supposed to be ProjectManager?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume what you want is to actually have a way to navigate to the productmanager / projectmanager from this class.  In that case, you could consider adding a navigation property to your model diagram for this class that would point to the underlying model that represents project/productmanager.

Comment: Thanks Stephen.  My question probably sounds a little strange - I'm coming from SQL background / entirely new to Entity Framework.  I guess the question is more "how" do I pull existing (and independently/separately updated) data into the model?  I suppose I could create a ProductManager.cs class in the Model to generate a table and use SSIS to update the table later on, but this is SQL dependent.  Do you know any tutorials / examples of syntax that would show how to "read" the other table data into the project?  (thanks / sorry again for how poorly this question is phrased)

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, my guess is that you already have some data in a table from which you want to pull it out along with some data from new tables that you'll create. If this is the case, here is a nice tutorial for that called [Using EF “Code First” with an Existing Database](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/03/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database.aspx) (step 5, in particular).